# Membership webpart to display the list of user irrespective of the logged in user access

Tags: web-part

We have a Membership webpart to display the list of users are in the site owners group, it displays the users if and only if the logged in user is a member or owner of the site however we want it to display the list of users all time irrespective of user permission, how do we can achieve this in a minimal effort..?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the "Who can view the membership of the group" property of the group from the default "Group members" to "everybody"?